# Laravel Response::json is not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Form as follows

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'POST','id'=>'personalInformation', 'class'=>'form-horizontal','route' => array('user.updatepersonalinformation', $user->id))) }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="John" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>


                        <div class="margiv-top-10">
                            <button  id="#btnSavePersonalInformation"  class="btn green">Save Personal Information </button>
                            <a href="#" class="btn default">Cancel </a>
                        </div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

and a route as such

```
Route::post('savePersonalInformation/{id}',['uses'=>'UsersController@savePersonalInformation', 'as'=>'user.updatepersonalinformation']);
```

The route method is plain and simple

```
    public function savePersonalInformation($id) {

    return Response::json(array('user' => $id));
}
```

I wish to submit this form using ajax. To this effect, I have the following code

```
$('#btnSavePersonalInformation').click(function() {
    var personalForm = $('#personalInformation');

    personalForm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: personalForm.attr('action'),
            data: personalForm.serialize(),
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            var jsonResponse = JSON().parse(response);
            alert  (jsonResponse[0]['Userid']);

        })
        .fail(function (response) {
            // Sending request to the server has failed
            // We'll show a notification that something went wrong
            console.log(response);

        })

    });
});
```

The form is called the exact message is in the route is dumped onto the screen, but no alert boxes are fired. What I mean is the result is dumped to the browser instead of me showing it to the user via the alert box .

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong here ?

**Update**
As stated below , I removed the JSON parse command altogether but I am still getting the same result. 
Here is the updated code

```
   $('#btnSavePersonalInformation').click(function() {
    var personalForm = $('#personalInformation');

    personalForm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: personalForm.attr('action'),
            data: personalForm.serialize(),
            dataType: "json"
        })
            .done(function (response) {

                alert  (response);

            })
            .fail(function (response) {
                // Sending request to the server has failed
                // We'll show a notification that something went wrong
                console.log(response);

            })

    });
});
```

thanks

Comment: Apart from the the fact, as mentioned below, your JSON call is wrong, you don't need to parse a response that's already parsed. (eg, jquery already parses the response).

Comment: @Daedalus : i removed the JSON parse command altogether , but I am still getting the same thing.

Comment: Give us the error message shown in your console; the alert should still fire if nothing is wrong, and display something like `[object Object]`.  In the case that its showing up in your browser console, something is indeed wrong and you need to check the content of that response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You may try this:

```
$('#btnSavePersonalInformation').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: personalForm.attr('action'),
        data: personalForm.serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        alert(response.user);
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

### Instead of something like this:

```
$('#btnSavePersonalInformation').click(function() {

    var personalForm = $('#personalInformation');

    personalForm.submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // ...

    });
});
```

### Depending on this server side method:

```
public function savePersonalInformation($id) {
    return Response::json(array('user' => $id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnSavePersonalInformation').click(function(e) {
            var personalForm = $('#personalInformation');

            personalForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: personalForm.attr('action'),
                    data: personalForm.serialize(),
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                .done(function (response) {                 
                    console.log(response.user);
                })
                .fail(function (response) {
                // Sending request to the server has failed
                // We'll show a notification that something went wrong
                console.log(response);

            })

            });
        });
    });

<button  id="btnSavePersonalInformation"  class="btn green">Save Personal Information </button>
```

Comment: Also remove the # from id="btnSavePersonalInformation"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have syntax issue with the [JSON.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.

It should be

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: I removed the Json Parse altogether as suggested above , but I am still getting the same thing.